# Run time error with my code VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I get an error for the below code, every time I try run it with a data set of about 25 million words.it says "Run-time error '91': object variable or With block variable not set" could anyone please assist. The aim of the program is to find a start and an end and delete everything inbetween.

```
Sub SomeSub()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String
    Dim Find1stRange As Range, FindEndRange As Range
    Dim DelRange As Range, DelStartRange As Range, DelEndRange As Range

    'Setting up the Ranges
    Set Find1stRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    Set FindEndRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    Set DelRange = ActiveDocument.Range

    'Set your Start and End Find words here to cleanup the script
    StartWord = "From: Research.TA@traditionanalytics.com"
    EndWord = "for malware by Websense. www.websense.com "

    'Starting the Find First Word
    With Find1stRange.Find
        .Text = StartWord
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Execute the Find
        Do While .Execute
            'If Found then do extra script
            If .Found = True Then
                'Setting the Found range to the DelStartRange
                Set DelStartRange = Find1stRange
                'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
                DelStartRange.Select

                'Setting the FindEndRange up for the remainder of the document form the end of the StartWord
                FindEndRange.Start = DelStartRange.End
                FindEndRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

                'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
                FindEndRange.Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                'Setting the Find to look for the End Word
                With FindEndRange.Find
                    .Text = EndWord
                    .Execute

                    'If Found then do extra script
                    If .Found = True Then
                        'Setting the Found range to the DelEndRange
                        Set DelEndRange = FindEndRange

                        'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
                        DelEndRange.Select

                    End If

                End With

                'Selecting the delete range
                DelRange.Start = DelStartRange.Start
                DelRange.End = DelEndRange.End
                'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
                DelRange.Select

                'Remove comment to actually delete
                DelRange.Delete



            End If      'Ending the If Find1stRange .Found = True
        Loop        'Ending the Do While .Execute Loop
    End With    'Ending the Find1stRange.Find With Statement

    End Sub
```

Comment: I what line does the error occur?

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late reply. But I get it in the DelRange.Select line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the run time error probably because the `DelEndRange` was not found.

Well in my testing this is what I found to be the problem.

So check that the `EndWord` text is actually in the document.